# chartjs horizontal bar chart get y position of each bar

Tags: chart.js

I have a plugin which should render a circle for each value in the dataset at the same height as each bar is. I can get the y position for a value with

chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(index)

but that is not the position of the bars.

```
   const data ={
  labels:[
    "Macht",
    "Ehre",
    "Besitz",
    [
      "Selbst-",
      "verwirklichung"
    ],
    "Wettbewerb",
    "Dienen",
    "Spiritualität"
  ],
  "datasets": [
    {
      "label": "first",
      "backgroundColor": "rgb(208,55,25)",
      "data": [
        4,
        8,
        5,
        4,
        1,
        1,
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "second",
      "backgroundColor": "rgb(240,223,89)",
      "data": [
        1,
        4,
        5,
        2,
        5,
        3,
        3
      ]
    }
  ]
}
const circles = {
  id: 'circles',
  afterDraw(chart, args, options) {
    const {ctx, scales:{x,y}} = chart;
    options.data.forEach((dataset) => {
      let even = true
      dataset.data.forEach((value,index) => {
        var xpos = x.getPixelForValue(value);
        var ypos = chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(index) //HERE I WANT THE Y POSITION OF EACH BAR
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = dataset.backgroundColor;
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.arc(xpos, ypos, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
      })
    })
  }
}
const chartOptions = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive:true,
  indexAxis: 'y',
  scales: {
    x:{
      min: 1,
      max: 9,
    },
    y:{
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 1,
        autoSkip: false,
      },
      min: 0,
      max: 6,
      position: 'left',

    },
  },
  plugins: {
    circles: {
      data: [
  {
    "label": "Selbseinschätzung",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(208,55,25)",
    "data": [
      6,
      4,
      3,
      7,
      4,
      4,
      7
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Selbseinschätzung",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(240,223,89)",
    "data": [
      7,
      4,
      4,
      3,
      6,
      5,
      2
    ]
  }
]
    }
  }
}


const ctx = document.getElementById('mts').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: chartOptions,
    plugins: [circles]
});
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I get the bars y position?

Now I have to give some more details, but I dont know how to explain the problem mor exactly. So I write this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the dataset element for y.

```js
const data ={
  labels:["Macht", "Ehre", "Besitz", ["Selbst-", "verwirklichung"], "Wettbewerb", "Dienen", "Spiritualität"],
  "datasets": [
    {
      "label": "first",
      "backgroundColor": "rgb(208,55,25)",
      "data": [4, 8, 5, 4, 1, 1, 3]
    },
    {
      "label": "second",
      "backgroundColor": "rgb(240,223,89)",
      "data": [1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 3]
    }
  ]
}
const circles = {
  id: 'circles',
  afterDraw(chart, args, options) {
    const {ctx, scales:{x,y}} = chart;
    options.data.forEach((dataset, dsIndex) => {
      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(dsIndex);
      let even = true
      dataset.data.forEach((value,index) => {
        var xpos = x.getPixelForValue(value);
        const elem = meta.data[index];
        //var ypos = y.getPixelForValue(index) //HERE I WANT THE Y POSITION OF EACH BAR
        var ypos = elem.y;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = dataset.backgroundColor;
        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.arc(xpos, ypos, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
      })
    })
  }
}
const chartOptions = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive:true,
  indexAxis: 'y',
  scales: {
    x:{
      min: 1,
      max: 9,
    },
    y:{
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 1,
        autoSkip: false,
      },
      min: 0,
      max: 6,
      position: 'left',

    },
  },
  plugins: {
    circles: {
      data: [
  {
    "label": "Selbseinschätzung",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(208,55,25)",
    "data": [
      6,
      4,
      3,
      7,
      4,
      4,
      7
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Selbseinschätzung",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(240,223,89)",
    "data": [
      7,
      4,
      4,
      3,
      6,
      5,
      2
    ]
  }
]
    }
  }
}


const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: chartOptions,
    plugins: [circles]
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```